# how to remove points in an array around NaN values within a window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I replaced outliners in a numpy array as

```
signal[signal > high_limit] = np.nan
```

I can locate the positions of those NaN values

```
nan_spots = np.where(np.isnan(signal))
```

But i am stuck to write a simple code to remove neighbor points around all NaN values by replacing them with `NaNs` as well, within of small window +-1 or so from the outliner.

Comment: Sounds like a [dilation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html).

Comment: Sounds like convolution of the result of isnan with a suitable step function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
border = 1
signal = np.array([1,2,3,4,np.nan, np.nan, 6,8,0,np.nan])
has_nan_nb = lambda i: any(np.isnan([signal[k] for k in range(i-border, i+border+1) if k!=i and k>=0 and k<len(signal)]))
signal[np.vectorize(has_nan_nb)(np.arrange(len(signal)))] = np.nan
```

That is easy in 1D problem.

Comment: perfect! worked! PS i am new to python, so did not know that lambda trick, and np.vectorize, thank you

Comment: @Blondinka Welcome to Python! Have Fun!